# glVertex: how to use other version of this call

Tags: opengl

I can only use glVertex3f in my computer,
which specifies the position of vertex by the ratio of x,y,z-axes.
Is there a way to specify the position of the vertex by giving the pixel numbers?
Then I can use integer numbers.

I know I can scale the view and then I can use glVertex3i.

Is there other way?

Like the example in redbook of OpenGL,
they directly use integer numbers in some calls.
I have to use some float number less than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using an apropriate projection

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0, window_width, 0, window_height, -1, 1)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()

# world XY coordinates now map to viewport XY
```

Keep in mind that immediate mode (`glBegin(...); for(...){ glVertex(...); } glEnd();`) is slow and deprecated. Use Vertex Arrays and Vertex Buffer Objects instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know that vertex arrays and buffers are faster.

Answer (score 0):

For normal coordinates, trying to get a 1:1 mapping from input numbers to pixel coordinates doesn't make much sense. In particular, all three coordinates interact with your projection matrix to map from a coordinate to a pixel position on screen.

OpenGL does have some bitmap functions (e.g., [`glBitmap`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBitmap.xml), [`glDrawPixels`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml)) that let you work directly in pixel coordinates. Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to guess whether that'll be useful for you.

Comment: I am just trying to read the redbook. there are some integral call not working on my machine.